# Change default browser in Katalon Studio

Tags: automation, automated-tests, katalon-studio

Whenever I open my project in Katalon and wanted to run my Test Case/Suite, I have default browser as `Firefox` as **default browser**. How can I change it and set it to *Chrome*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open Katalon Studio > Open your project
- Navigate menu to Project > Settings. Then Execution > Default.
- Change you `Default Execution` to `Chrome`.
- Set Apply and ok.

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in 
 project/Settings/internal/com.kms.katalon.execution.setting.properties

Should have a line like this: 
execution.default.executionConfiguration="Chrome"

Since ours is in git and Katalon (unhelpfully) adds a timestamp at the top, I had to check in without that timestamp and all is good.